# cURL Login Content not Showing

Tags: php, authentication, curl, post, cookies

I have now managed the login with cURL. This is confirmed by the following:

Cookie.txt:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

www.profi-ortung.de    FALSE    /    FALSE    0    PHPSESSID    hg1e550nsu10h4elgbo65hrtsm
```

If I log in manually, the log says that the login is working:

1. Windows  Firefox 1.0.7   28-05-2020 09:56:33

Why can't I see the content of the user, i.e. home.php?

The basic code:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.profi-ortung.de/login.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
//set the cookie the site has for certain features, this is optional
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "cookiename=0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=xxx@xxx&password=xxx");
curl_exec($ch);

//page with the content I want to grab
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.profi-ortung.de/home.php");
//do stuff with the info with DomDocument() etc
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: You have asked the exact same question yesterday already. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62043798/curl-login-not-working-on-www-profi-ortung-de-index-php

Comment: @Realitätsverlust I don’t think it is exactly the same, the main point of the other question appears to have been, _“A Cookie.txt is created but with the parameter false.”_ - so there seems to have been some progress here between these two questions at least.

Comment: You need to set up your second request properly. Now, you are just making it with pretty much all of the options still set to the same values, as with the first request - for example, the request method here is still POST. I rather doubt this is _actually_ the request you wanted to make for the `/home.php` URL.